# Invalid XML view architecture issue - OpenErp

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo

I got this code in my module.py

```
class certificados(osv.osv):

_name = 'certificados.certificados'
_description="Certificados de No Produccion"
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']

_columns = {
        'Item' : fields.integer('Item'), 'Registro_Numero' : fields.integer('Registro Numero'),
        'Fecha_de_Emision': fields.date('Fecha de Emision', required=True, select=True),
        'Fecha_de_Solicitud': fields.date('Fecha de Solicitud', required=True, select=True),
        'Fecha_del_Documento': fields.date('Fecha del Documento', required=True, select=True),
        'Vigencia' : fields.integer('Vigencia'), 'cert_ids' : fields.one2many('certificados.line','requisicion_id','Items del Certificado',states={'done': [('readonly', True)]}),
        'descripcion' : fields.text('Descripcion'),
        'notas' : fields.text('Notas'),
        }

class certificados_line(osv.osv):

_name = "certificados.line"
_description="Certificados No Produccion"

_columns = {
'Codigo_Arancelario' : fields.integer('Codigo Arancelario'),
'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Material'),
'Descripcion_Arancelaria' : fields.char('Descripcion Arancelaria', size=42, required = True, translate = True), 
'Especificaciones_Tecnicas' : fields.char('Especificaciones Tecnicas', size=60, required = True, translate = True), 
'Cantidad' : fields.float('Cantidad'), 'Unidad_de_Medida': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Unidad de Medida'),
'Precio_Unitario_Declarado' : fields.float('Precio Unitario Declarado'), 'Moneda' : fields.many2one('res.currency', 'Moneda'),
'Valor_En_Divisas' : fields.float('Valor En Divisas'),
'requisicion_id' : fields.many2one('certificados.certificados', 'Certificados de No Produccion', ondelete='cascade'),
'Cantidad_Consumida' : fields.float('Cantidad Consumida'), 'Cantidad_Disponible' : fields.float('Cantidad Disponible'),

}
certificados_line()
```

And the form view model in my module_view.xml

```
 <record id="student_certificados_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">certificados.result.form</field>
        <field name="model">certificados.certificados</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Introducir los datos" version="7.0">
                <sheet>
                    <div class="oe_edit_only">
                        <label for="Registro_Numero" class="oe_inline"/>
                    </div>
                    <h1>
                        <field name="Registro_Numero" class="oe_inline"/>
                    </h1>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="Fecha_de_Emision"/>
                            <field name="Fecha_de_Solicitud"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="Fecha_del_Documento"/>
                            <field name="Vigencia"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Productos">
                            <field name="cert_ids">
                                <tree string="Productos">
                                    <field name="product_id"/>
                                    <field name="Codigo_Arancelario"/>
                                    <field name="Descripcion_Arancelaria"/>
                                    <field name="Especificaciones_Tecnicas"/>
                                    <field name="Cantidad"/>
                                    <field name="Precio_Unitario_Declarado"/>
                                    <field name="Valor_En_Divisas"/>
                                    <field name="Cantidad_Consumida"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                            <separator string="Observaciones"/>
                            <field name="descripcion"/>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
                <div class="oe_chatter">
                    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                </div> 
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

There's more code in the xml, but this is the interesting one, i mean, i guess the invalid architecture error is because of the model i'm using (certificados.certificados), because the (cert_ids) is calling another class called (certificados_line), so, my question is, how can i embed more than one model in a form view?

I saw in another module called purchase_requisition, that this is possible, but for some reason i can't accomplish it with this one, any ideas?

Comment: You should post your error also.

Comment: [XML Error](http://pastebin.com/Bc0fh69s) There it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Problem**
Latest first discuss about your search view of certificados.

In the search view you added field which does not exits in object **certificados.certificados**
You have added field   `<field name="Valor_En_Divisas" string="Valor En Divisas" />` but actually this field exits in object **certificados.line**

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="certificados_search">
            <field name="name">certificados.search</field>
            <field name="model">certificados.certificados</field>
            <field name="type">search</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Buscar Certificados" >
                <field name="notas" string="Notas" />

                <field name="Valor_En_Divisas" string="Valor En Divisas" />
            </search>
            </field>
        </record>
```

**Now discuss about your second problem**

```
<record id="certificados_certificados_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">certificados.result.tree.new</field>
                <field name="model">certificados.certificados</field>
                <field name="type">tree</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                        <tree string="Crear_Certificado" >
                                <field name="Item" />
                                <field name="Codigo_Arancelario" />
                                <field name="Descripcion_Arancelaria" />
                                <field name="Especificaciones_Tecnicas" />
                                <field name="Precio_Unitario_Declarado" />
                                <field name="Valor_En_Divisas" />
                                <field name="Cantidad_Consumida" />
                                <field name="Cantidad_Disponible" />

                        </tree>
                </field>
        </record>
```

In this tree view you define for object **certificados.certificados** just one field related to this object `<field name="Item" />` all other fields are related to **certificados.line** object.

when you remove the field which belong to **certificados.line** from search and form view then it works perfectly.

As i told , i just solved one problem from previous question , these two problem also in your view, when define your tree view or search view , plz take in consideration to put field of that object owns.

Comment: Geez, i can't believe i didn't notice, thanks you very much, i'll try it tomorrow (it's 1 am here) but thank you, you saved my life!

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very very much! Awesome as usual! it just gave me another tricky problem but i asked this in another question. Thank you.